# .NET CORE 2.2 Identity + Basic Auth for WebAPI

Tags: c#, .net-core, basic-authentication, asp.net-core-identity

I am developing a software which contains User-Interfaces and APIs. For the authentication and authorization i have used .NET CORE Identity 2.2!

I works very well. Now i have API functions which have two different requirements:
 1. API Endpoint which is used by User-Interfaces (AJAX calls and so on...)
 2. API Endpoint which could be used by other Software

Therefore i would like to use two different Authorize-Methods. For point 1 i use the .NET CORE Identity authorization and authentication. And for point 2 i would like to use BASIC AUTH

How could i configure these different Authorize-Methods. Here is a sample code:

**BASIC AUTH CODE**

1. Try to add Service-Support for BasuicAuth in ConfigureServices
   `services.AddAuthentication("BasicAuth").AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthHandler>("BasicAuth", null);`
2. Build Basic Auth Handler

   ```
   public class BasicAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
   {

       IConfiguration _configuration;

       /// <summary>
       /// Constructor
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="options"></param>
       /// <param name="logger"></param>
       /// <param name="encoder"></param>
       /// <param name="clock"></param>
       /// <param name="configuration"></param>
       public BasicAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock, IConfiguration configuration) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
       {
           _configuration = configuration;
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Handels the Authentication by using Basic Auth
       /// --> Checks the configured values by 
       /// </summary>
       /// <returns></returns>
       protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
       {
           if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
           {
               return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Missing Authorization Header");
           }
           try
           {
               var authHeader = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(Request.Headers["Authorization"]);
               var credentialsByes = Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Parameter);
               var credentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(credentialsByes).Split(':');

               var configuredUserName = _configuration["BasicAuth:Username"];
               var configuredPassword = _configuration["BasicAuth:Password"];

               if (configuredUserName.Equals(credentials[0]) & configuredPassword.Equals(credentials[1]))
               {
                   var claims = new[] {
                       new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, credentials[0])
                   };
                   var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
                   var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                   var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);
                   return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
               }
               else
               {
                   return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Credentials");
               }
           }
           catch
           {
               return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Authorization Header");
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Try to add Authentication Basic-Auth to Controller

   ```
   [ApiController]
   [ApiVersion("1.0", Deprecated = false)]
   [Produces("application/json")]
   [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
   [Authorize]
   public class MasterDataController : ControllerBase
   {...}
   ```

   ***The Authorize Annotation is using every-time the .NET CORE Identity Authorize***

**ANOTHER CASE IS TO USE AUTHORIZE BY .NET CORE IDENTITY FOR UI-APIs**

```
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1.0", Deprecated = false)]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[Authorize(Roles = "SuperUser,PlantAdministrator,EndUser")]
public class UploadController : ControllerBase
{...}
```

**This works very well - but i would like to use a combination...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. You could do it by add parameters to the Authorize annotation like the following:

```
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1.0", Deprecated = false)]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "BasicAuth")]
public class MasterDataController : ControllerBase
{...}
```

If you set the ActiveAuthenticationSchemes to Basic Auth it looks for a compatible AuthenticationHandler!